# Is there a way to automatically sync a background-image source with most recent instagram post?

Tags: html, css, scripting, background-image, instagram

I would like to use HTML and CSS to create a custom block on Squarespace.

The idea is to have an image, when you hover over it you will see the text "Follow On Instagram". This will be a clickable image that will take you to Instagram.

I want the image to automatically show the most recent post on Instagram.

I have already figured out how to create a static background image with the hover function.  I just don't know how (or if it's possible) to make that image automatically update.

I have tried pasting the most recent image URL address of a Squarespace Instagram block, but the image does not change when a new photo is posted to Instagram.

```
<div class="container-6">
 <img class="image-6" src="//*an image url address*//" >

<a href="http://instagram.com/"><div class="overlay-6">
   <div class="text-6">VitaLife on Instagram</div> </div></a></div>


<style>
.container-6 {position: relative;text-align:center;}

.overlay-6 {position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;opacity: 0;transition: 0.75s ease;background-color: white;}

.container-6:hover .overlay-6 {opacity: 1;  transition: .25s ease;}

.text-6 {position: absolute;}
</style>
```

Comment: Look for instagram's API and endpoints. You might need to make an AJAX request to that URL so everytime there is a change on instagram your images will change. https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: Thank you Julian! I'll look into that.